# Why does the simple chat Server-Client always give me a BindException?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, chat

Why does the code below gives the following exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at chap15.VerySimpleChatServer.go(VerySimpleChatServer.java:42)
    at chap15.VerySimpleChatServer.main(VerySimpleChatServer.java:36)
```

I tried compiling it with netbeans. I created a project and put both classes inside it.
This is an example of the book "Head First Java", chapter 15

SERVER:

```
package chap15;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class VerySimpleChatServer
{
    ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket sock;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSOcket) {
            try {
                sock = clientSOcket;
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

            } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read " + message);
                    tellEveryone(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
    }

    public void go() {
        clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                t.start();
                System.out.println("got a connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void tellEveryone(String message) {
        Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
                writer.println(message);
                writer.flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos Well it's not very minimal, it's including GUI code not related to the sockets...

Comment: Minimal doesn't mean "only the essential".

Comment: GUI code is not relevant to a networking question. Please remove it and reduce it to the essentials. Actually your client code isn't relevant at all, only the server code.

Comment: Are you actually trying to send a message (string) to this class (server) ? Because you would need another class (in chapter 15 this class is called SimpleChatClient.java) that first starts a GUI where you can put in a string and actually send it to the class VerySimpleChatServer. What you are doing here is trying to start the same server twice which gives you the  BindException. Also it may be easier to delete the package name in every class at the top and compile all the classes you need with your current version of JDK. This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The code "as posted in here" works.

You must have an old thread stuck or a process that is stuck somewhere. This happens if you were debugging it and didn't give it a chance to shut down properly.

Answer (score 0):

Because something else is listening at the port, probably a prior instance of your own program that you haven't terminated yet. Or else you terminated it but there are still ports in TIME_WAIT state, which lasts for two minutes after the last inbound connection is closed.

Comment: How do i close it? because i have already tried more than 20 ports and none of them works

Comment: Find the process that is using it, with 'netstat'.

Comment: Another issue is that you aren't closing the client socket in the server when you've reached end of stream.

Comment: There was many TIME_WAIT ports and i closed them using TCPView, but i still have the BindException issue. You mean i use finally statement after  try {while ((message = reader.readLine()) ... and inside the finally put reader.close(); sock.close(); for (PrintWriter writer : clientOutputStreams) {writer.close();} ?

Comment: Well you do have to `close()` something, and also remove it from any lists of things that are supposed to be opened. What that means in your application is up to you. If you still get a `BindException` after dealing with all the `TIME_WAIT` ports then somethign must still be listening. Again, you can determine what via `netstat.`